# HTML5 full-screen doesn't work when set inside a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying this code. It is supposed to generate an image and set its container `div` to full-screen when the `p` is clicked.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img { height: 643px; width: 860px; }
img:-moz-full-screen { height: 643px; width: 860px; }
div:-moz-full-screen { background: white; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 $("p").click(function() {    
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("body").prepend("<div><img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBZKC.jpg?s=128&g=1' /></div>");
    $("div").get(0).mozRequestFullScreen();
  },5000);
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Foo</p>
</body>
```

What it does is wiat for 5 seconds and prepend the image all right, but it is not set to full-screen. However, if you remove the timer and do it normally:

```
$("p").click(function() {
  $("body").prepend("<div><img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBZKC.jpg?s=128&g=1' /></div>");
  $("div").get(0).mozRequestFullScreen();
});
```

it works fine, it prepends the image and immediately sets it to full-screen.

Is this intentional, or a bug? Either way, is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has to be called in response to a user input event (ie. keypress, mouseevent).

Comment: Yeah, we are doing just that. It is supposed to fire on a `click` event, only we are delaying it by 2 seconds..

Comment: Yes and that's the problem. The input event has to be directly part of the callstack during invocation. Which is not the case if the call is delayed using a timer.

Comment: Okay. So is there no way to make it work, like some hack or something?

Comment: No there's no workaround because this security feature is there for a reason.